# Cant run composer update in putty command line

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

In my local directory, I just installed beautymail for laravel email sending, but when I go to my putty app and type `composer require snowfire/beautymail dev-master` It gives me an error of

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-16:/var/www/html/domain-payment$ composer require snowfire/beautymail dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Snowfire\Beautymail\BeautymailServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How could I fix this? I already pushed my code to repo and after that I want to install the beautymail package because in my local directory, i already published the asset of beautymail. Can someone tell me what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: you run `composer require` locally to build the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file, the lock ends up in your repo and on the server and you run `composer install` on the server to make the packages match what is in the lock file; you don't run `composer update` or `composer require` on the server

Comment: try this [link](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-composer)

Comment: i already did that in my local directory sir and pushed to repo. whenever i run composer update or install in putty, the beautymail package is not included there

Comment: you don't run `composer update` on the server, you are not updating dependencies on the server

Comment: what should i run sir? @lagbox

Comment: make sure you have published that library. `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Snowfire\Beautymail\BeautymailServiceProvider"`

Comment: yes, i already published the library, but when i publish the library in putty, it says `Class 'Snowfire\Beautymail\BeautymailServiceProvider' not found
`

Comment: and also i cant publish the library because in my composer.json the `beautymail` package is not in there, even if i do `composer require beautymail.....` it gets me error @DilipHirapara

Comment: if you added that service provider to `config/app.php` you can remove it .. if this package gets installed it uses auto discovery which will register the provider for you .. this will also allow you to have access to your application without that error for the moment

Comment: Remove that `Snowfire\Beautymail\BeautymailServiceProvider` line from `config/app.php`..then `composer update` and then again publish.

Comment: no there is no reason to run `composer update`

Comment: how to remove that snowfire sir in config? Could i open it in putty terminal?

Comment: edit it locally, push the changes to your repo, on the server pull the changes, etc etc

Comment: After i removed the `Snowfire\Beautymail\BeautymailServiceProvider` from config i will push into repo and pull from server. what should i do next @DilipHirapara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Your vendor folder and then install composer

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this file

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
   "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master"
}
```

And than run this command

```
composer install
```